# Swift CollectionView Display Wrong

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I have a collection view in my app.
I want to set each item to have a different color.
I use a switch case, as follows.

```
switch indexPath.row {
        case 0: cell.label.text = "0"
            cell.label.textColor = .blue
        case 1: cell.label.text = "1"
        case 2: cell.label.text = "2"
        case 3: cell.label.text = "3"
        case 4: cell.label.text = "4"
        case 5: cell.label.text = "5"
        default: cell.label.text = "6"
        }
```

I have set the default color light gray to the label.
But if I set case 0 to blue color, case 0 and 5 will display blue.
I set case 1 to blue color, case 1 and 4 will display blue.

Comment: set the colour to light grey in each of the other cases. Otherwise dequeuing will create multiple same cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `UICollectionView` has a mechanism to reuse the cell's instance. So that's why you should handle `cell.label.textColor` in every single case. If not it will be uncontrollable whenever `cellForItemAt indexPath` delegate is called. Please try:

```swift
switch indexPath.row {
case 0:
    cell.label.text = "0"
    cell.label.textColor = .blue
case 1:
    cell.label.text = "1"
    cell.label.textColor = .red
case 2:
    cell.label.text = "2"
    cell.label.textColor = .orange
case 3:
    cell.label.text = "3"
    cell.label.textColor = .purple
case 4:
    cell.label.text = "4"
    cell.label.textColor = .blue
case 5:
    cell.label.text = "5"
    cell.label.textColor = .blue
default:
    cell.label.text = "6"
    cell.label.textColor = .blue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to default color first then before starting switch case set the label default color. In `switch` case you can update color based on condition.

Like this:

```
cell.label.textColor = .ligthGray

switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: cell.label.text = "0"
        cell.label.textColor = .blue
    case 1: cell.label.text = "1"
    case 2: cell.label.text = "2"
    case 3: cell.label.text = "3"
    case 4: cell.label.text = "4"
    case 5: cell.label.text = "5"
    default: cell.label.text = "6"
    }
```

In this case only the `0` indexed label will be `blue` color and the others will be `lightGray`